# Is it possible to use navigator.getDisplayMedia without user authentication?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, navigator

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: true
  }).then(gotMedia).catch(function(e) {
    console.log('getDisplayMedia() error: ', e);
  });
```

when executing the above code it prompts with a popup asking user to select what to share. Can we get rid of that popup and directly get the stream of the entire screen?

Would be glad if someone can help with the same. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: one word ... security `get the stream of the whole computer` ... the what? the stream? I've build hundreds of computers in my time, and not one contains a stream (except that time I screwed up a connection on the water cooling, but that was more of a leak)

Comment: Added a screenshot and changed the minor word flaw.

Comment: so, you addressed the frivolous part of my comment, and decided there is no security issue with what you want to do? Do you understand why this would be a bad thing?

Comment: Sorry could not figure out your comment first. Yes I know there is a security issue. Still I need clear idea on this.  Can you please explain a bit in detail. Thanks

Comment: detail: If I go to some website, I don't want to automatically share my screen - do you?

Comment: Yes but in case of getUserMedia to access camera we provide the authentication once and after that the browser does not ask for the same. But for the getDisplayMedia it is not the same. It always asks even if we are using the same tab.

Comment: In my case I'm wanting to do something similar with an internal app running in Chromium using computers we control, but wanting the simplest user experience for users who are not tech savvy.

Answer (score 5):

For automated testing it is possible to preselect a window with a Chrome command line argument [--auto-select-desktop-capture-source](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#auto-select-desktop-capture-source)

This Chrome issue is the best available documentation: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459532

Comment: I there the same setting for Firefox ?

Comment: @Phillip Hancke  there is also mentioned: Generate a preferences file with persistent perms How do we use it  in JS?
prefs: {
      "profile": {
        "content_settings": {
          "exceptions": {
            "media_stream_camera": {
              "https://*,*": {
               "setting": 1
              }
            },
            "media_stream_mic": {
              "https://*,*": {
               "setting": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }