# Entire screen sharing Media Stream getDiplayMedia()

Tags: javascript, mediastream, screensharing, mediadevices, get-display-media

I want to let the user share his screen, I use getDisplayMedia() to let the user start sharing and it let him choose entire screen or chrome … etc.
so my question is: can I let the user always choose the entire screen, like not giving him the option of other type sharing like window … like putting constraints on it or something
I tried displaySurface = 'monitor' but it didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use navigator.getDisplayMedia without user authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956289/is-it-possible-to-use-navigator-getdisplaymedia-without-user-authentication)

Comment: Thanks for replying, but unfortunately it doesn't, i don't want it to start sharing without user authentication, i just want it to let the user select only the entire screen when he want to share his screen

Answer (score 4):

You can do work around.

You can check `displaySurface`,if it is not `monitor`(entire screen) then you can reject the promise and inside reject handler you can **stop** and **start** again.

```
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getDisplayMedia()
  .then((strm) => {
    let displaySurface = strm.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings().displaySurface;
    if (displaySurface !== 'monitor') {
      throw 'Selection of entire screen mandatory!';
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));//Here you can stop and start again
```